# How to add (n,) array to (n,m) array in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Consider having two arrays:
`A` with shape `(n,)`
`B` with shape `(n,m)`

How can I add those two together so that `A[i]` is added to all m values of `B[i]`?
Surely I could do it with for loops, but I want to learn how to properly use numpy.
So what's an elegant way to do it in numpy?

Example for `(n,) + (n,m)`:

```
A = [1,2]
B = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
A + B should be [[2,3,4],[6,7,8]]
```

It would also be interesting how I could add the other way `(n,) + (m,n)`:

```
A = [1,2,3]
B = [[1,2,3],[3,4,5]]
A + B should be [[2,4,6],[4,6,8]]
```

Edit:
The shapes I meant aren't the same as I wrote down.
The first example is not `(n,1)+(n,m)` and the second example is not `(n,1)+(m,n)`.
Before this edit I confused `(n,)` with `(n,1)`. (and with `(1,n)`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numpy has a feature named `broadcasting`. See the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

> The term broadcasting describes how numpy treats arrays with different shapes during arithmetic operations. Subject to certain constraints, the smaller array is “broadcast” across the larger array so that they have compatible shapes. Broadcasting provides a means of vectorizing array operations so that looping occurs in C instead of Python. It does this without making needless copies of data and usually leads to efficient algorithm implementations. There are, however, cases where broadcasting is a bad idea because it leads to inefficient use of memory that slows computation.

You can add this two arrays, you should just change dims of array A

```
A = np.array([1,2,3]).reshape(1,3)
B = np.array([[1,2,3],[3,4,5]])  # this is already 2 dimensional

print(A + B)
```

Comment: `[1,2,3].reshape(1,3)` answers the second part of my question, but what about `(2,1)+(2,3)` like in the first example?

Comment: @NicoG.: Your input does not have shape `(2,1)`. If it did, you could just use `+`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I have a small question regarding this: Is the shape `(n,)` the same as `(n,1)` or `(1,n)`?

Comment: @NicoG.: Neither. `(n,)` is a 1-dimensional shape. `(n,1)` and `(1,n)` shapes are both 2-dimensional. Learning to use NumPy necessarily involves getting out of a matrix-oriented mindset; NumPy does not treat 2D as special. (Note that the comma in `(n,)` isn't a separator between `n` and some sort of empty thing; it's part of the syntax for a length-1 tuple, because `(n)` just means `n`.)

Answer (score 3):

It *would* literally be just `A + B`, but your inputs aren't the arrays you think they are.

Your inputs are nested lists, and converted to arrays, your `A` examples are 1D, not 2D. Your inputs should look like

```
A = numpy.array([[1],[2]])
B = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
```

Then `A + B` would work.

Comment: This is not what I wanted to know, because I already have those arrays and don't want to change the input. I guess `reshape` would suit the problem like @Sekomer pointed out. (At least for the 2nd example)

Comment: Then again, if `A` already is `numpy.array([1,2])`, one can reshape it before summing up: `A.reshape(2, 1) + B`

Answer (score 0):

```
In [46]: A = [1,2]
    ...: B = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
In [47]: A+B
Out[47]: [1, 2, [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Addition for lists is a join.  But if you really mean you have arrays:

```
In [48]: AA = np.array(A); BB = np.array(B)
In [49]: AA+BB
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-49-14674959eb4e>", line 1, in <module>
    AA+BB
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (2,3)
```

But by making the first (2,1) shape, that does work:

```
In [50]: AA[:,None]+BB
Out[50]: 
array([[2, 3, 4],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

The 2nd case works without modification, adding a (3,) to (2,3).  The first is automatically promoted to (1,3).  Adding the lead dimension is automatic; trailing dimensions are your responsibility:

```
In [51]: A = np.array([1,2,3])
    ...: B = np.array([[1,2,3],[3,4,5]])
In [52]: A+B
Out[52]: 
array([[2, 4, 6],
       [4, 6, 8]])
```